# Calculating variance explained by factors in an ANOVA in a factorial design

Tags: anova, variance

I am performing an ANOVA on a dataset with three discrete fixed factors (treatment A with 10 levels; Treatment B with three levels; and 4 sites) which includes all possible interactions. It is completely orthogonal and balanced. Aside from determining whether treatments and interactions are statistically significant, I would like to present how much variance in the model is explained by each factor and interaction. In this way I hope I can demonstrate the relative importance of each factor in determining the trait of interest.

What would be a simple way to correctly report the variance described by each simple and interaction term in an ANOVA model? Is it as simple as dividing the sum of squares for each term by the total, or do I need to adjust by the number of levels in each terms (or something more complicated)?